# How to draw a rectangle using a char parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, char, drawing

I want to draw and fill a rectangle using C++. The function parameter passed in must be a char, not an int. In my header file the drawing function is this:

```
void draw(char);
```

My rectangle.cpp file is this:

```
void rectangle::draw(char )
{
    for(height=0;height<=height;height++)
    {
        for(width=1;width<=width;width++)
        {
            cout<<'*';
        }
    }
}
```

My main.cpp file is this:

```
rectangle d1;
d1.draw(char);
```

When I run the program it gives me the error:

> Expected primary expression before 'char'.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12. Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `for` loops are incorrect; try a simpler task that involves a `for` loop. Then we can talk about how to call a function.

Comment: And you must name your parameter, i.e `void rectangle::draw(char c)`

Comment: And you must do _something_ with that char c parameter

Comment: I want to use '* ' to fill a rectangle with char parameter but I don't know how to use.In the for loop I must draw and fill this rectangle that I take in the parameter.Should I define that char c='*' in the header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your draw is missing a variable. Change  `draw(char);` to `draw(char c);`
And both `for` loops need a maximum range, not the same value as the incrementing variable. `height<=height;` and `width<=width;`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void draw(char c )
{
    int rheight=10;
    int rwidth=20;

    for(int height=0;height<=rheight;height++)
    {
        for(int width=1;width<=rwidth;width++)
        {
            cout<<c;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}


int main()
{

    draw('*');
    cout<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```